# How to define function in JSX

Tags: reactjs

I am pretty new to React, what I want to do is periodically generate several numbers and update the view:

```js
<script type="text/jsx">
      var ChartFrame = React.createClass({
        datagenerator: function(n, itvl){
          function randomD(){
            data2fill = [];
            for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
              data.push(Math.random()*10);
            }
            this.setState({
              "data": data
            });
          }
          var counter = setInterval(randomD, itvl);
          return counter;
        },
        getInitialState: function(){
          return {
            data:(function(){  
              this.state.counter = this.datagenerator(5, 1000); 
              return [];  
            })()
          }
        },
        render:  function(){
          var ds = this.state.data;
          var divs = ds.map(function(d, i){
            return <div>   d   </div>;
          });
          return (
            {divs}
          );
        }
      });
      React.render(<ChartFrame />, document.body);
<script>
```

However, I get the error message below:

**Uncaught TypeError: this.datagenerator is not a function**

I wonder what is the correct way to define function in JSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've declared your function is correct but your entire `getInitialState` is messed up, yo.

What would be the desired behavior here? Since you've declared a new function it will not have access to the correct `this` which would be the component unless you `.bind()` it. Unsure what it does or how it works, read [this great article](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/). The code is below

```
return {
    data:(function(){  
        this.state.counter = this.datagenerator(5, 1000); 
        return [];  
    }.bind(this))()
}
```

However doing that will produce another error for you, `this.state` is `undefined` hence you will not be able to set `counter` on `this.state`.

`this.state` is never set in `getInitialState` since the job of the function is to produce the state. Also you're returning an empty array to the data which will lead to `this.state.data` be an empty Array.

Furthermore, you might want to start your `datagenerator` function within the life cycle method [#componentDidMount](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) in order for state to have been set and the first render has occurred.

And as a complimentary treat, [your code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/f0gfpw1a/)!